# Swift 4 NSUnknownKeyException Error

Tags: xcode, ipad, swift4

After yesterdays update I got a pretty strange error when trying to run my app.

```
2018-06-14 10:38:25.882062+0200 Sorglos Lagerbestand[377:21124] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Sorglos_Lagerbestand.genexis 0x1017d05d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lbl_titanium.'
```

I got three ViewControllers which got all the same function. 2 are working just fine without any problem but the third one is not working at all. Everytime I'm trying to get into that buggy viewcontroller the app freezes.

You guys got any solution for that?

Whole code: https://hastebin.com/vegoboxipo.swift

---

Comment: Show the code...

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to paste the code.
https://hastebin.com/vegoboxipo.swift

Comment: `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`, that's a well known issue. Did you look for it? The class `genexis` doesn't have a `lbl_titanium` property (a `UILabel` I guess), while you did so in the InterfaceBuilder. Check your `IBOutlet` for it.

Comment: @Larme thank you! Work fine now! :)